# AngularJS 1.2 to 1.3 clientWidth no longer correct

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On updating angular to version 1.3.9 from 1.2 I ran into a snag with clientWidth and the like. Before they were returning the correct DOM value, but now they are returning 0. The element is in the DOM at this point, the css sets the width to 100%, not sure what the updating to angular had to do with this. Any insight would be great.

Thanks in advance!

```
var $m = angular.module('quad.insights.time', ['src/time/time.html','quad.insights.utils']);

$m.directive('timeChart',['$compile','$filter','utils','dateFilter',function($compile,$filter,utils,dateFilter) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        id: '@',
        data: '=',
        metadata: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        window['_timeScope'] = scope;


        scope.render = function() {
            var data = getData();
            if (!data) return;

            function containerWidth() {
             return element[0].querySelector('.qi-time-lines').clientWidth ; // returning 0 with 1.3 update
            }
            function containerHeight() { return element[0].querySelector('.qi-time-lines').clientHeight // returning 0 with 1.3 update }

            var rangeAbs = function(d){ return range(d) * containerHeight() };
            var domainAbs = d3.scale.linear().domain([lowDate,highDate]).range([ 0, containerWidth() ]);
            $compile(element)(scope);
            return;
        }

        scope.$watch('data',scope.render,true);
    },
    templateUrl: 'src/time/time.html'
}
}]);
```

Comment: I wonder if it's a race condition where render is executing after the model has been set, but before the view has been bound. You could put the body of the render function in a `$timeout` to test if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way, but it fixes this issue to me:

Set as a custom directive:

```
angular.module('appControllers').directive('ngChart', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.elementReady(element);
    }
});
```

and then on the controller:

```
$scope.elementReady = function(el){
    console.log(el[0].clientWidth); // <- Right width here
}
```